# Spring boot keycloak authenticated example, cannot authenticate via postman jwt, only via keycloak screen

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid, spring-security-oauth2

I am following this example by Baeldung https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak in order to implement something similar in my code.

However, access by just JWT doesnt work, it only works via the login screen. Check questions at the end.

In the code example, not in my code, just clone the repo, get a keycloak server and run it, everything works as planned when trying to access `http://localhost:8081/customers`

The app redirects to keycloak login, I enter the credentials and the API returns the data as seen in the pictures below

[image]

[image]

So the example fully works.

BUT, when acquiring the token by postman, successfully as below, I cannot access the resource from postman by entering the token as authentication bearer.

[image]

The app still redirects me to login to keycloak screen

[image]

1. Why does this happen?
2. What could I do to get access both ways, by the login screen and the JWT token?

The debug logs from the app are

```
12:11:49.133 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler - adminRequest http://localhost:8081/customers
12:11:49.137 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils - Using provider 'secret' for authentication of client 'login-app'
12:11:49.138 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils - Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
12:11:49.139 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils - Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
12:11:49.139 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils - Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret-jwt
12:11:49.139 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils - Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret
12:11:49.139 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils - Loaded clientCredentialsProvider jwt
12:11:49.139 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.a.a.ClientCredentialsProviderUtils - Loaded clientCredentialsProvider secret-jwt
12:11:49.145 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.a.t.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve - AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke /customers
12:11:49.145 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler - AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:8081/customers
12:11:49.145 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler - Policy enforcement is disabled.
12:11:49.147 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
12:11:49.147 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
12:11:49.147 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
12:11:49.147 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
12:11:49.147 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected FixedThemeResolver
12:11:49.148 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@28b16193
12:11:49.148 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@5d56c2d2
12:11:49.148 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
12:11:49.148 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 1 ms
12:11:49.155 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /customers
12:11:49.158 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
12:11:49.160 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
12:11:49.160 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.SessionManagementFilter - Request requested invalid session id 2188C37ADF15140FB15235D80AAA0C77
12:11:49.165 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /customers] with attributes [authenticated]
12:11:49.207 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - Saved request http://localhost:8081/customers to session
12:11:49.207 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Trying to match using And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], Not [And [Or [Ant [pattern='/login'], Ant [pattern='/favicon.ico']], And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy@21fa9d8, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]]]]
12:11:49.207 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint@681b92a9
12:11:49.207 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to http://localhost:8081/oauth2/authorization/keycloak
12:11:49.208 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
12:11:49.209 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
12:11:49.209 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
12:11:49.228 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] DEBUG o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler - adminRequest http://localhost:8081/oauth2/authorization/keycloak
12:11:49.229 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] DEBUG o.k.a.t.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve - AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke /oauth2/authorization/keycloak
12:11:49.229 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] DEBUG o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler - AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke http://localhost:8081/oauth2/authorization/keycloak
12:11:49.229 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] DEBUG o.k.a.AuthenticatedActionsHandler - Policy enforcement is disabled.
12:11:49.229 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /oauth2/authorization/keycloak
12:11:49.229 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
12:11:49.234 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to http://localhost:8090/auth/realms/main-authentication/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=login-app&scope=openid&state=aoSFWCq-HdIiwwi_SB8oKFI29T2EJhHQmlz0e8h9RAY%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/keycloak&nonce=Dlsh8t93QaYB3oqVvAtlvssCEF_UBxdibFHfyIPGnv4
12:11:49.234 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
12:11:49.234 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Did not store empty SecurityContext
12:11:49.234 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

I have tried to play around with the `grant_type` to `client_credentials` , `password` but nothing works. I also tried commenting out the `http.oauth2Login()`. Still no luck

Following other examples and applying keycloak security as an adapter by `extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, the behavior was better actually, access was possible both ways. But this is about to be deprecated.

EDIT 1: I could post trace logs if someone needs

Answer (score 1):

This Baeldung blog post you're refering to configures a Spring OAurh2 **client**: it serves UI with Thymeleaf pages (and it is not "official").

If you're trying to build a REST API with OAuth2 security, then you should look at tutorials for configuring a **resource-server** instead. Like [this one](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

Also, do not use Keycloak adapters for spring, [it is already deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187) (like very deprecated if you look at transient dependencies).

Comment: You are right, it's not official, i will modify the title and description. Any insight on my questions though?

Comment: Actually, I think I answered your question when I write that you should configure REST APIs as resource-servers and not as clients. Just read the tutorials linked.